# Can someone explain why document.write does not write the body tag in this example?

Tags: javascript

Given the following HTML with a small JS snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const iframeEl = document.createElement("iframe");
        document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);

        const htmlToWrite = "<html><head><title><\/title><script src=\"javascript:void(0)\" defer=\"\"><\/script><\/head><body><\/body><\/html>";

        const iframeDocument = iframeEl.contentWindow.document;
        iframeDocument.open();
        iframeDocument.write(htmlToWrite);
        iframeDocument.close();

        const bodyEl = iframeDocument.querySelector("body");
        console.log("Has body element", bodyEl != null);
        if (bodyEl == null) {
            console.log("Got", iframeDocument.documentElement.outerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

if I remove the defer attribute from the script tag, document.write no longer writes the body tag. Can someone explain why this is happening?

I would expect that it writes out the rest of the document, even if the script src isn't loadable.

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what the problem is. The `defer` attribute means the script will not run until the page has finished loading, so it makes sense to me that removing `defer` means that the script won't be executed.

Comment: Right. The problem is that when you remove the defer attribute, the body tag is not written to the iframe.

Comment: How do you know the `<body>` isn't being created? By inspecting the iframe document, or because the `querySelector` is not returning it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that browsers will infer the `<body>` if the HTML doesn't include one. Which makes me suspect your test, since I feel like no browser would actually construct the DOM you describe even if forced to at gunpoint. As a rule, browsers go to extreme lengths to salvage bad markup (not that yours is bad).